# Is Pymodbus compatible with MicroPython?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, micropython, pymodbus

I'm starting an IoT project and I've decided to use the NodeMCU board. The project consists of remote monitoring of electrical grids, so then it is composed of a module which takes a lot of data from a power grid analyzer and then sends that to a remote server through the internet. I decided to use NodeMCU because it has already implemented a WiFi interface and it's very cheap. However, I have realized I'm going to have problems with the communication with the power grid analyzer because that one has an RS485 interface and implements the Modbus protocol. There is no problem with the RS485 interface because I'm going to use an adaptor to UART, but I wasn't been able to find a Modbus library for MicroPython.
So the question is, is Pymodbus compatible with MicroPython? And also, is it compatible with the NodeMCU board?

Answer (score 1):

The NodeMCU based on the ESP8266 is very resource constrained, ~ 64K RAM of which micropython alone takes around 30K at boot. Pymodbus is pretty huge, even running synchronously it still needs pyserial which doesn't seem to be ported to micropython. see https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=6534 .Basically I don't think that any amount of hacking and freezing into the firmware would work.

I currently read modbus data over RS485 from an Epsolar device using an ESP8266. I use micropython-modbus

https://github.com/techbase123/micropython-modbus

(adapted for the ESP32 from pycom-modbus) which I have further hacked for use by the ESP8266, mainly by removing unnecessary args from the **init** method of uModBusSerial, together with subsequent references to them and changing a few imports to their MICROpython equivalents. It reads values just fine but writing only works for some values for me.
Alternatively maybe try a board based on an ESP32 , with ~500K RAM (and a ton of other features) with pymodbus and either port pyserial to micropython or follow advice about reading over UART in the first link

https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/general.html

Comment: does micropython-modbus support RTU master?